Flutter iOS: Error (Xcode): Embedded binary's bundle idenfitier is not prefixed with the parent app's bundle identifier
When I try to run flutter build ipa I get following error:
Error (Xcode): Embedded binary's bundle idenfitier is not prefixed with the parent app's bundle identifier.

Encountered error while archiving for device.

But when I try to run app in simulator from Xcode it works as expected.
These are my build steps:
Build phases of an app
So far I couldn't find any solution, I changed Flutter channel to master and beta without effect, tried changing order of build phases, looked at bundle ids but found only one in the picture which as I read OneSignal documentation is required to be named like so. Tried also deleting temporary xcode files but it didn't help too
